# URL to open page with a non-default filter?

Tags: html, jquery

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="news__triggers">
        <a href="#" class="news__triggers__item active" data-cat=".all">All</a>
        <a href=".#press-releases" class="news__triggers__item" data-cat=".press-releases">Press Releases</a>
        <a href=".#publications" class="news__triggers__item" data-cat=".publications">Publications</a>
    </div>
```

The js function is this:

```
function newsFilter() {
    $('.news__triggers a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var cat = $(this).data('cat');

        console.log(cat);

        $('.news__triggers__item').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.section-news__posts .post').fadeOut(1);
        $( '.section-news__posts ' + cat).fadeIn(200);

    });

    $('.news__select').selectmenu({
        change : function(){
            var cat = $(this).val();
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $('.section-news__posts .post').fadeOut(1);
            $('.section-news__posts '+ cat).fadeIn(200);
    }});
}
```

This are the posts being filtered.
It's working to filter by category. The default filter is "all", I need to link to another one for example "publication" and make it active.

```
<div class="section-news__posts">
    <div class="post all publications" data-category-type="publications" style="">
    Lorem ipsum text
    </div>
    <div class="post all press-releases" data-category-type="press-releases" style="">
    Lorem ipsum text
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to make it work so if I have an url like https://example.com/page/#publications, it goes to that page with publication filter being active.

Comment: Please explain the specific problem in more detail. You haven't identified what is not working or even what  *"publication filter"* or *"non-default filter"* are. The dots in the `href` seem very strange also. See [ask]

Comment: I updated the question with more details

Comment: You want `window.location.hash` to get the `"#publications"` from url. Then remove the `#` from that string